# android resource failed to load

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gradle-plugin, android-resources

```
Android resource linking failed
/Users/suhaibaskar/Downloads/AndroidStudioProjects#Sqlite/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml:1: error: resource dimen/activity_vertical_margin (aka com.example.myapplication:dimen/activity_vertical_margin) not found.

/Users/suhaibaskar/Downloads/AndroidStudioProjects#Sqlite/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml:1: error: resource dimen/activity_horizontal_margin (aka com.example.myapplication:dimen/activity_horizontal_margin) not found.  

/Users/suhaibaskar/Downloads/AndroidStudioProjects#Sqlite/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml:1: error: resource dimen/activity_horizontal_margin (aka com.example.myapplication:dimen/activity_horizontal_margin) not found.  

/Users/suhaibaskar/Downloads/AndroidStudioProjects#Sqlite/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml:1: error: resource dimen/activity_vertical_margin (aka com.example.myapplication:dimen/activity_vertical_margin) not found.
error: failed linking file resources.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

error: failed linking file resources. this error occur because of missing dimen file

first of all create dimen file in values package
follow these steps to create dimen file:

**Path**

**Right click on values > New > values resource file > set name (dimen)  then press ok**

add dimen in dimen file like this

```
<resources>
<dimen name="fab_margin">16dp</dimen>
<!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="nav_header_vertical_spacing">8dp</dimen>
<dimen name="nav_header_height">176dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

I hope its work for you